# Can't find graphicsmagick... but it's installed?

Tags: ubuntu, meteor, imagemagick, graphicsmagick

I am using mupx to deploy a meteor build. Graphicsmagick is installed on the system (as well as imagemagick), both using apt-get on ubuntu 14.04. My app is failing when trying to transform an image. This is the error I get:

```
[wyno.io] FS.Transform.createWriteStream transform function failed, Error: 
[wyno.io] Exception in queued task: Error: cfs:graphicsmagick could not find "graphicsMagick" or "imageMagick"
[wyno.io]     at gm (packages/cfs_graphicsmagick/packages/cfs_graphicsmagick.js:14:1)
[wyno.io]     at Object.FS.Collection.stores.FS.Store.GridFS.transformWrite (both/collections.js:10:1)
[wyno.io]     at packages/cfs_storage-adapter/packages/cfs_storage-adapter.js:355:1
[wyno.io]     at addPassThrough (packages/cfs_storage-adapter/packages/cfs_storage-adapter.js:421:1)
[wyno.io]     at [object Object].FS.Transform.createWriteStream (packages/cfs_storage-adapter/packages/cfs_storage-adapter.js:352:1)
[wyno.io]     at Object.self.adapter.createWriteStream (packages/cfs_storage-adapter/packages/cfs_storage-adapter.js:171:1)
[wyno.io]     at saveCopy (packages/cfs_worker/packages/cfs_worker.js:180:1)
[wyno.io]     at Object.fsCollection.files.find.observe.added (packages/cfs_worker/packages/cfs_worker.js:42:1)
[wyno.io]     at [object Object].observeChangesCallbacks.added (packages/minimongo/observe.js:153:1)
[wyno.io]     at self.applyChange.added (packages/minimongo/observe.js:53:1)
```

Comment: Looks like both graphicsMagick and imageMagick are not under the $PATH of your application process owner (According to the sourcecode https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-cfs-graphicsmagick/blob/master/gm.js). could you provide more infomation about your deployment environment? (e,g, EC2)

Comment: Yeah, sure. I'm deploying to a Digitial Ocean droplet with Ubuntu 14.04. I just installed graphicsmagick/imagemagick using apt-get install. MUP recognized that they were there when deploying to this server, as it stopped giving me the error at deploy time, but now I get this error when I try to call the transform function at run time.

Comment: @RyanWu any chance you can deduce another step forward from this info? I'm still stuck on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the solution to this is installing it manually, not via apt-get. Here are the steps for doing so:

1. Get the tar gz file from their ftp server. make sure to get the most recent .tar.gz version available.

   `$ wget ftp://ftp.graphicsmagick.org/pub/GraphicsMagick/1.3/GraphicsMagick-1.3.1.tar.gz`
2. `$ tar -xvzf GraphicsMagick-1.3.1.tar.gz`
3. `$ cd GraphicsMagick-1.3.1/`
4. `$ ./configure`
5. `$ make`
6. `$ make install`

If you don't have a c compiler on your server, there is a step 3.5: `sudo apt-get install build-essential`